# An issue with installation of ansible-pylibssh on Apple Silicon M2

Tags: ansible

I've got an  issue with installation of ansible-pylibssh.
During installation

```
pip3 install --user ansible-pylibssh
```

I got

```
ld: library not found for -lssh
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
```

Could someone explain how to overcome this?

I've already done softlink

```
% cd /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
% sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/Cellar/libssh/0.10.4/include/libssh/ libssh
```

Comment: clang is already installed.      
nec@192 Documents % clang -v
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

Answer (score 1):

Install libssh:

```bash
brew install libssh
```

Use a python virtual environment :

```bash
python3 -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
```

EDIT:
Install with correct compiler flags:

```bash
CFLAGS="-I $(brew --prefix)/include -I ext -L $(brew --prefix)/lib -lssh" pip install ansible-pylibssh
```

Thanks, [@webknjaz](https://tox.wiki/)!

OLD Additional steps not needed (preserved for history):

Install [tox](https://tox.wiki/) build tool:

```bash
pip install 'tox >= 3.19.0'
```

Build from source on ARM-based Macs, per the [ansible-pylibssh docs](https://ansible-pylibssh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation_guide/):

```bash
#git clone https://github.com/ansible/pylibssh.git ~/src/github/ansible/pylibssh
# or, if you use SSH:
git clone ssh://git@github.com/ansible/pylibssh.git ~/src/github/ansible/pylibssh
cd ~/src/github/ansible/pylibssh
```

[Use libraries installed by brew with clang](https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/3792):

```bash
export CFLAGS="-I $(brew --prefix)/include -I ext -L $(brew --prefix)/lib -lssh"
```

Build ansible-pylibssh:

```bash
tox -e build-dists
```

Install built `ansible-pylibssh` wheel:

```bash
pip install ~/src/github/ansible/pylibssh/dist/ansible_pylibssh*.whl
```

Additional resources that lead to this answer:

- [Kristof Rado](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74048900)'s answer to [Cannot install ansible-pylibssh on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74048675/cannot-install-ansible-pylibssh-on-macos/75473525)
- [ansible/pylibssh GitHub issue 207](https://github.com/ansible/pylibssh/issues/207) provides background on why this package is not available for macOS on ARM from PyPi (symlink/softlink to point to the libraries did not help. Correct compiler flags were the needed answer.)

If you prefer not to work with a virtual environment, this may work: replace `pip` commands `python3 -m pip --user` and `python` commands with `python3`.